# Formula for "complex" pairwise comparisons

Tags: math, statistics

I am looking for a general formula to generate the number of pairwise comparisons needed to match this special type of data.
For example, we have 2 experimental conditions and each sample receives a combination of the two. We'll call one diet and the other exercise. Each subject is given both a specific diet (a,b,c) and an exercise (1,2,3).
There are 9 subjects for each combination:

```
a1 a2 a3
b1 b2 b3
c1 c2 c3
```

We would like to do a pairwise comparison between only subjects that share one category, i.e. a1 and b1 (the diets are the same, but the exercises are different), or a1 and a2 (the exercises are the same, but the diets are different). a1 would not be compared to b2 in this because they do not share a group. a1 and a1 are also not compared because they are the same subject.

There are 18 comparisons in this scenario:

```
a1 & a2
a1 & a3
a1 & b1
a1 & c1
a2 & a3
a2 & b2
a2 & c2
a3 & b3
a3 & c3
b1 & b2
b1 & b3
b1 & c1
b2 & b3
b2 & c2
b3 & c3
c1 & c2
c1 & c3
c2 & c3
```

I would like some general formula to be able to calculate the number of comparisons needed with n and m sized experimental group conditions. In this case there is n=3 (diet) and m=3 (exercise).

I imagine there it is some variation of 9 choose 3 (36).

Thanks, please feel free to ask any additional questions.

Comment: For an N by M table, is the number N * (M choose 2) + M * (N choose 2)?

Comment: that seems to work on the examples I did by hand. I am curious how you came up with that.

Comment: Suppose that each element is comparable only with elements in the same row or column. Then, we have (n_cols choose 2) comparisons within each row times the number of rows, i.e. n_rows * (n_cols choose 2). The other side is symmetric.